# Prove that normed space and dual space have same dimension

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a normed space and $V^*$ be a dual space of $V$ (over $R$). I try to prove that $dim(V)=dim(V^*)$.

I discuss two cases for dimension of $V$:

I can prove the finite dimensional case as follows.

**But how to prove the statement as $dim(V)=\infty$?** I think that we need to show if $dim(V)=\infty$, then $dim(V^*)=\infty$? But how to do that?

---

As $dim(V)<\infty$. Assume that $dim(V)=n$.

Let $\omega\in V^*$ and let $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ be a basis for $V$. Define $e^i\in V^*$ by $$e^i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$$.

1. $\{e^1,...,e^n\}$ spans $V^*$. $\omega(v)=\omega(v_1e_1+...+v_ne_n)=v_1\omega(e_1)+...+v_n\omega(e_n).$ If $\omega(e_1)=\lambda_1,...,\omega(e_n)=\lambda_n$, then $\omega(v)=v_1\lambda_1e^1(e_1)+...+v_n\lambda_ne^n(e_n)$=$\lambda_1e^1(v)+...+\lambda_ne^n(v)$.
2. $\{e^1,...,e^n\}$ is linearly independent. Suppose that $0=c_1e^1+...+c_ne^n$ is the zero mapping to $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the image of $e_1:$  $0(e_1)=c_1*1+...+c_n*0=c_1$ Hence, $c_1=0$. Repeating the procedure for $e_j$, $2\leq j\leq n$, we see that $c_1=c_2=...=c_n=0$.

Comment: It is not true in infinite dimension that the dimension of $V$ is equal to its dual (not even for its topological dual). While they are both "infinite" they are in general not the same (same as $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ do not have the same cardinality).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $dim (V^{*})<\infty$ then $dim (V^{**})<\infty$ and there is a canonical injective linear map from $V$ to $V^{**}$ making $V$ finite dimensional.

Comment: I have proved that if $V^{*}$ is finite dimensional then so is $V$. This means that if $V$ is infinite dimensional then so is $V^{*}$.  Is this not what you want? @Hermi

Comment: First question: You have proved that $V$ f.d. implies $V^{*}$ f.d. Just replace $V$ by $V^{*}$. Second question:  An injectibe linear maps takes  a basis to a linearly independent set. So it cannot decrease the dimension. @Hermi

Comment: Let $N$ be the dimension of $V^{**}$. If $V$ is infinite dimensional then we can find $N+1$ linearly independent vectors in $V$ and they get mapped to $N+1$ linearly independent vectors in $V^{**}$. This is  a contradictioin.  @Hermi

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in my comment above, it is in general not true for normed spaces that $\dim(V)=\dim(V^*)$, independent of whether we mean the topological or the algebraic dual.

For a counterexample, pick your favourite normed vector $V$ space with countable Hamel basis, e.g. $c_{00}=\{ (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \ : \ \text{ only finitely many } a_n \neq 0 \}$ with the sup-norm. The topological dual $V^*$ is a Banach space ([Intuition: Dual Space is always Banach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099048/intuition-dual-space-is-always-banach)). Let's assume that $V^*$ had a countable Hamel basis, then $V^*$ would be incomplete by an application of Baire's theorem (see [Countable dimensional normed space incomplete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824460/countable-dimensional-normed-space-incomplete)), which yields a contradiction. In particular, this gives that $\dim(V^*)$ is uncountable.

If for you $V^*$ denotes the algebraic dual, then it is still not true as the topological dual is a subspace of the algebraic dual and hence the algebraic dual has also an uncountable basis.

In the nice answer above by geetha290krm it is shown that if $V^*$ is finite-dimensional, then $V$ is finite dimensional too. Or, in other words, if $V$ is infinite-dimensional, then so is $V^*$. The key fact used here is that the map $V\rightarrow V^{**}, x \mapsto (\varphi \mapsto \varphi(x))$ is an injection (use Hahn-Banach to show that it is an injection by constructing a linear functional $\varphi_x$ such that $\varphi_x(x)\neq 0$).

Comment: Yes. I know they are not same. But if dim(V)=$\infty$. How to prove that $dim(V^*)=\infty$.

Comment: @Hermi Then you should not write that you want to prove that they are the same. The dimension of a vector space is defined to be the cardinality of one of its bases and so $\infty$ is not a valid output. I have not repeated a proof for "$V$ infinite-dimensional $\Rightarrow $ $V^*$ infinite-dimensional" as it is already covered by geeta290krm. The point is that we have the injection $V\rightarrow V^{**}, x \mapsto (\varphi \mapsto \varphi(x))$, i.e. the evaluations are in the bidual. This means that the dimension of $V^{**}$ is at least the dimension of $V$ [cont.]

Comment: However, if $V^*$ was finite-dimensional, then $V^{**}$ would be finite-dimensional too, which yields a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

For finite dimensional $V$ and $W$, you have the general relationship
$$\mathrm{dim}(L(V,W)) = \mathrm{dim}V \mathrm{dim} W$$ where $L(V,W)$ is the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $W$. If you haven't seen this, you may consider the bijection that translates a linear transformation to a matrix. Armed with this, it follows that:
$$\mathrm{dim}V^* = \mathrm{dim} (L(V, \mathbb{F})) = \mathrm{dim} V \mathrm{dim}\mathbb{F} = \mathrm{dim}V$$